# Как восстановить пароль?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Как реализовать восстановление пароля?

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :lname, :name, :password, :password_confirmation

  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :lname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, :on => :create
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, :allow_blank => true
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, :on => :create

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :upadate, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :profile]
  before_filter :admin_user, only: :destroy

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @users = User.text_search(params[:query]).paginate(page: params[:page], :order => :'created_at DESC', :per_page => 20)
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def profile
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def job
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  private

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

session_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Comment: Так а что у вас не получается?

Answer (score 1):

По следующей логике например:

1. Добавить в таблицу users поле `reset_password_token default: ''`
2. Добавить в `SessionsController` действие с показом формы для ввода адреса почты
3. Как только адрес отправлен вам, ищем его в базе, если есть, создаем токен, пишем его в `reset_password_token`, отсылаем на этот адрес ссылку вида `site.com/sessions/resetpass?token=тут_созданный_токен`
4. Как только юзер пришел по этой ссылке ищем `params[:token]` в базе, если есть, рисуем форму для нового пароля и удаляем токен из базы

а дальше дело техники. 
Вопрос: почему не devise?
И создайте в `UsersController` метод `get_user` например, засуньте его в `before_filter` для `show`, `profile` и `job`

Comment: создал password_recovers_controller.ru

  class PasswordRecoversController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end
 
    def create
      user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
      user.send_password_recover if user
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

в user.rb добавил

    def send_password_recover
      create_remember_token(:reset_password_token)
      self.password_recover_sent_at = Time.zone.now
      save!
      UserMailer.password_recover(self).deliver
    end

выдает ошибку
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: params[:session] потому что nil, к тому же когда это вы email в сессию сохраняете?

как говорится, "учи мат. часть", это основы основ, есть виде на railscasts, есть масса реализованных gem'ов (devise тот-же).